# What is this skinny black caterpillar with brown on the head and tail and a stripe on the back?

Tags: identification, trees, pests

I found this caterpillar and several of its buddies on my hummingbird tree this morning. It's skinny and mostly black, but it has interesting brown areas on the face and tail. There's also a stripe down its back.

A friend suggested it might be a fritillary, but it doesn’t look like any photos of fritillary caterpillars I found.

What kind of caterpillar is this?

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's a moth or butterfly larvae, it strongly resembles one of the sawfly larvae - I just don't know which, but they're not usually good news...

Comment: what part of the world are you in?

Comment: League City Texas

Comment: I'm unable to find this particular larvae, but I'm still fairly sure its a sawfly. If you notice flowers or foliage being eaten, and there are lots of them and picking them off and stomping on them is too difficult to keep up with,then an insecticide spray may be called for,but only as a last resort.